# How do you categorize your languages and technologies on resumes or promotion materials?

Tags: taxonomy

I have them categorized like this:

```
       TECHNOLOGIES
             Scripting:   Ruby, PHP, ColdFusion, Perl, Javascript/AJAX
             Compiled:    ActionScript3, C, C++, Objective C, Java, J2ME, Assembly
             Frameworks:  Ruby On Rails, Flex, Flash, Smarty. Wordpress, Joomla, Thematic
             API’s:       Facebook, Twitter, Imeem, Google, and custom API’s
             Formats:     XHTML, CSS, XML, JSON
             Server:      Apache , MySQL, SQLite, CRON
             Libraries:   Prototype, JQuery, Scriptaculous, ImageMagick, Capistrano

APPLICATIONS

                      GIT, SVN, TextMate, Adobe Photoshop, Eclipse, NetBeans, IAR, Matlab, PSPICE

    PLATFORMS
                      Linux, Unix, OS X, DOS, Windows
```

Comment: That's too much information.  You should tailor it to the specfic job you are applying for otherwise it may look like you're a mile wide and an inch deep in all of them.  Highlight some specific technologies in descriptions of recent work that you've done.

Comment: I agree with tvanfosson, makes you look like you touched each and then moved on to something else, I as an employer would question how much time you spent with each to really make it on the resume.  So tailor the set to what job you apply for or what promo you setup for.

Comment: My resume is being sent to a consulting company, so I kinda want to show them all I got.

Comment: Also you better watch out for the Apostrophic Jihad! http://angryflower.com/plural.gif http://angryflower.com/bobsqu.gif

Comment: And there is this trivial thing that make your CV look, well, trivial. I wouldn't put "cron" just like I wouldn't put "Control Panel" or "Notepad". I'd explain a bit my level on each platform and let that do the job. Mixing Apache and MySQL with CRON looks awful to me. Unless you are talking about a real server named cron which is not crontab (if this is the case, my apologies)

Comment: @Vinko - I agree that "cat's" is a possessive, not a plural, however "'s" is preferred when pluralizing an acronym, as in "API's". Yes, it's counterintuitive, and no I don't like it.

Comment: @Vinko - thanks and I agree with you.  I removed CRON, Imagemageick, Capistrano, IAR, Matlab, and PSPICE.  Definitely helped unclutter a bit. @Bob - i think Vinko is right.  i did some googling

Comment: @Bob Also, according to your source, what's the possesive of an acronym? "API's I know" "The API's methods" like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I group like this:

```
Languages
   C++, Java, Javascript, SQL

Platforms and Environments
   .NET, Linux, Windows...

Significant Tools and Technologies
    Rational Rose, Silverlight, AJAX
```

I purposely keep it to three categories, so that for *each* opportunity, I can easily reorder things to stress that decision maker's priorities. Also, I continually cull the individual items to make sure that the only items I've listed are those that I'm willing to discuss in an interview, and that I would want to work with in a new position.

Comment: This is a sane approach. And only bring forward the parts of your experience that actually matters. As tvanfosson said, you could look a mile wide and an inch deep with too much information. There is also the possibility that they will reject you because they think that you make stuff up if you include too much.